# Imagemapster for jQuery 3.1.1

Tags: jquery, imagemapster

I'm using Imagemapster but since upgrading to jQuery 3.3.1 the Imagemapster is throwing an error "i.size is not a function". I've googled it up and since Imagemapster is not updated for jQuery 3.3.1 I tried replacing 'i.size' with 'i.length' but now I'm getting error that 'i.length is not a function'.

```
split:function(e,t){var n,r,i=e.split(",");for(n=0;n<i.length;n++)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since the last release of this library was in 2013, I'd consider using [jQuery noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) in order to use both the new jQuery version and the old one that supports the library.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- revert global jQuery and $ variables and store jQuery in a new variable -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jQuery_3_3_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 1.3.2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>

<!-- revert global jQuery and $ variables and store jQuery in a new variable -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jQuery_1_3_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

This way you can keep your support for the ImageMapster but also use the updated jQuery.